# Cloudflare IP range error

Tags: ip, cloudflare, whitelist

I need to whitelist an IP ranges 91.232.230.0/23 and 79.142.16.0/20 on CloudFlare. If I enter these IP ranges I get the error: An IP range (CIDR) must be a /16 or /24

How can I whitelist these?

I've submitted a ticket, but haven't heard anything from them yet.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they truly only allow `/16` and `/24` entries in the whitelist, you could use two `/24` entries to represent the `/23` network and sixteen `/24` entries to represent the `/20` network.

Comment: Alternately, you could go more permissive and make two entries that encompass those two ranges. I think that would be two /16 networks, which is a fair bit wider than the /20 and /23.

Comment: If I understand correctly I should add 91.232.231.0/24 and 91.232.230.0/24 to represent the 91.232.230.0/23 ? And for 79.142.16.0/20: 79.142.16.0/24
79.142.17.0/24
79.142.18.0/24
79.142.19.0/24
79.142.20.0/24
79.142.21.0/24
79.142.22.0/24
79.142.23.0/24
79.142.24.0/24
79.142.25.0/24
79.142.26.0/24
79.142.27.0/24
79.142.28.0/24
79.142.29.0/24
79.142.30.0/24
79.142.31.0/24

Comment: @LindaRigas Looks correct